# Java сервер на 2-х клиентов

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос - возможно ли сделать на java сервер для 2х клиентов? Клиенты будут располагаться на разных пк, также нужно, чтобы клиенты общались через этот сервер.

Comment: Ответ всегда таков: ВОЗМОЖНО ВСЕ, вопрос только во времени. Но такую программку сделать не очень сложно. А для локальной сети и того просто. Надо просто посмотреть соответсвующую литературу

Comment: А не подскажите какую литературу мне нужно посмотреть чтобы написать сервер,я сам пишу программы на AutoIt и JavaScript ещё не изучил,просто сложно перейти с одного языка на другой,сделал 2 клиента а сервер нужен для того что бы передавать ip адреса другому клиенту,то есть я не уточнил,у меня 2 приложения клиет-сервер нужно просто организовать передачу ip адресов.

Comment: Я с этим не работал. Просто как-то мельком попалось в глаза что-то похожее. Есть стандартные сетевые Java-технологии, которых можно найти в толстых книгах, и даже на русском. Может кто знает, и напишет вам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно. К примеру, через сокеты. Хватит обычной книги по java. Протокол обмена можно сделать самому (к примеру, простые текстовые посылки в виде запрос-ответ).

К примеру, вот класс из моего старого проекта (передает / принимает данные на любой компьютер, где есть ответная часть):

```
package cav;

import java.net.*;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SendReciveData
{
    private Socket sockX;
    private BufferedReader ios;
    private BufferedWriter oos;
    private WrkBase wDB;
    private Window wpf;

    public SendReciveData (int mode)
    {
        try
        {
            String ip = InvPref.getKey ("IP_ADRESS").toString ();
            int lPort = UtilsCav.strToInt (InvPref.getKey ("Port").toString ());
            sockX = new Socket (ip, lPort);
            ios = 
              new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (sockX.getInputStream ()));
            oos = 
              new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter (sockX.getOutputStream ()));
            wDB = new WrkBase ();
            String str;
            String param = null;
            if (mode == 0)
            {
                // прием данных
                while (true)
                {
                    str = ios.readLine ();
                    if (UtilsCav.wordCount (str, "~") > 1)
                    {
                        String[]sf = UtilsCav.getSplit (str, "~");
                        param = sf[1];
                        str = sf[0];
                    }
                    if (str.equals ("READY"))
                    {
                        wDB.clearBarName ();
                        oos.write ("GET");
                        oos.flush ();
                    }
                    if (str.equals ("RECIVE"))
                    {
                        if (param.equals ("END"))
                        {
                            oos.write ("END");
                            oos.flush ();
                            break;
                        }
                        String[]sb = UtilsCav.getSplit (param, ";");
                        wDB.addRecord (sb[1], sb[0]);
                        oos.write ("RECIVE_NEXT");
                        oos.flush ();
                    }
                    if (str.equals ("END"))
                    {
                        closeSock ();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //передача данных
                int i = 0;
                while (true)
                {
                    str = ios.readLine ();
                    if (str.equals ("READY"))
                    {
                        oos.write ("SEND_START " + wDB.getRecCount ());
                        oos.flush ();
                    }
                    if (str.equals ("SEND_ST_OK"))
                    {
                        String sx = wDB.getRecord (i);
                        i = i + 1;
                        if (i <= (wDB.getRecCount ()))
                        {
                            oos.write ("SEND " + sx);
                            oos.flush ();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            oos.write ("END");
                            oos.flush ();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (str.equals ("SEND_NEXT"))
                    {
                        String sx = wDB.getRecord (i);
                        i = i + 1;
                        if (i <= wDB.getRecCount ())
                        {
                            oos.write ("SEND " + sx);
                            oos.flush ();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            oos.write ("END");
                            oos.flush ();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println ("T>" + e.getMessage ());
            UtilsCav.addLog ("T>" + e.getMessage ());
        }
        System.out.println ("Exit cicl");
    }

    public void closeSock ()
    {
        try
        {
            sockX.close ();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println (">close: " + e.getMessage ());
            UtilsCav.addLog (">close: " + e.getMessage ());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не очень разбираюсь, но это, по-моему, написано не *.js, а JAVA скрипт, то есть его компилировать нужно и пользоваться как приложением?

Comment: Всё,разобрался,большое спасибо